# Hide last page pagination in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, code-snippets

it is possible in WordPress to delete or hide the last page of the pagination, in order to allow users to continue the search without giving them the possibility of seeing the last page.

And then insert a block in the search page (e.g.) the search is blocked until page 150 or 200. Beyond 150 "no search results" will be displayed.

Maybe inserting a snippet could solve it?

Comment: This would more likely be possible to achieve programmaticaly. I don't really see a snippet/widget proposing this. It's really not my turf so this may comes as silly, but isn't it contrary to ui/ux ways? I'm not sure you're supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pre_get_posts` hook to modify the query for the pagination. In this case, you want to prevent the last page from being displayed. Add the following code to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function custom_modify_pagination($query) {
  if (is_search() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $max_page = $query->max_num_pages;

    // Specify the page number you want to hide
    $hide_page = 150;

    if ($max_page >= $hide_page) {
      $query->set('paged', $hide_page - 1);
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_modify_pagination');
```

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work, I solved it via css